# Grails app metrics to prove asynchronous calls result in better response times

Tags: grails, asynchronous, promise, future, completable-future

I currently have a grails app, running on grails 2.4.2 which seems to be using java futures to make REST calls in a blocking fashion as follows

```
Future<Map<String,Object>> future1 = service.getMetrics(args1)
Future<Map<String,Object>> future2 = service.getMetrics(args2)

Map<String,Object> result1 = future1.get(10, TimeUnit.DAYS.MINUTES)
Map<String,Object> result2 = future2.get(10, TimeUnit.DAYS.MINUTES)
```

My goal is to refactor this code to be asynchronous as the above snippet of code seems to defeat the purpose of using asynchronous programming by calling the "blocking" get function immediately. I am considering the following options

1. [Grails Promises](http://grails.github.io/grails-doc/2.4.2/guide/async.html)
2. [Guava Listenable Future](https://code.google.com/p/guava-libraries/wiki/ListenableFutureExplained)
3. [Java 8: Completable Future](http://www.nurkiewicz.com/2013/05/java-8-definitive-guide-to.html)

My question is not around which options to consider but more around is there a simple , trivial way to measure the metrics to show that using a non-blocking call will provide better response time to users accessing the grails web-app.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if this will help you in your travels, but I was playing around with what sounds like much the same problem. I was trying to find out if I multi-threaded a portion of my code, if it would ultimately cut down on the entire request time. Some parts of my method were simply too small to benefit from threading.

Here's a link to a snippet of code I paste at the top of the method I'm testing for metrics. Once I've tuned the method, I remove this code:

https://gist.github.com/mikedehaan/ed2751601046b6d1d078

This allows me to decorate the method with gotHere() statements that print timing from the start of the method and time between gotHere() calls.

Example:

```
gotHere("Start Process");

def promise1 = task {
    // Do something that takes time
}

// Do something else while we're waiting for promise1 to finish

// Block until promise1 completes
def result = promise1.get();

gotHere("Process Finished");
```

This isn't a permanent metrics solution, but it certainly helped me tune methods for performance.

Hope this helps.